# Insert content from one website into another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two websites which display the same content. I would like to be able to have the content on one site and display it on the other (so I only have to update one site when I need to make amends).

Is there a way to do this using jquery??

Something like this:

`$(".site2div).append($("http://www.mysite.com").find(".site1div").innerhtml());`

Comment: This may be possible with jQuery, but I must say it's certainly not the best tool for the job, possibly even the worst tool.

Comment: Whether it's possible or not, I would not recommend this method of synchronization. The second site will always have outdated content and only dynamically change itself upon loading.  What about when the user has JavaScript disabled? What about search engines?

Comment: You'd be better off with a server-side (Perl) solution that actually edits the HTML files on demand or by a schedule. For example: A Perl script would be on the server of the clone site and it would read whatever specified HTML is publicly accessible on your source site. Then it would write this text into the specified HTML file on the clone site, one time, permanently changing it. You could call this Perl script once after you make a change to the source site or put it on a cron schedule.

Comment: If both sites have identical content, why do you need two unique sites?  AFAIK, Google frowns upon this practice.

Comment: It's only one particular part of each site that has duplicate content... a "Getting there" section to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

You will have cross-domain security issues:

http://jsfiddle.net/KYVFy/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('http://www.google.com', function(data) {
    $("#jackedContent").html(data);
 });
});
```

So more likely you will have to have some type of "web proxy service" on the server side to communicate across domains.

Answer (score 0):

If your minimum browser to support is IE8 or higher, there's a new standard with better handles this:  Cross-Originl Resource Sharing (CORS) [[wiki]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) [[browser support]](http://caniuse.com/#search=cross-origin).  As others have pointed out the **browser** fundamentally controls which domains you can access content from, however CORS allows **the** domain to specify who can access the content.  If you control both websites or are partnered with the other website setting up an allow rule for CORS might be worth looking into.  Again, only IE8 and above currently supports this.